Where does Postman 5.5.6 store its history?
I was using Postman 5.5.6, which is a Google Chrome extension.
Yesterday, I discovered that I can no longer access it, resulting in the loss of all my stored histories.
By 'histories,' I mean the web service or API URLs and examples (such as content-type and JSON strings) stored within it.
I'm wondering how I can retrieve all of my lost histories.
I am currently using Postman v10.24. Although I'm not logged in, it allows me to import history by prompting me for the cURL. However, I'm unsure where to find the cURL from Postman 5.5.6.

History is part of collection stored in level database format
C:\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Postman\IndexedDB


I looked under C:\Users<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Postman, there is no IndexedDB folder or file.

also Check under AppData\Local\Postman\  OR  AppData \*\Postman\
